# Create Array url_options for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails application default url for post is _http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/7,  how can i display  url like this _http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/cer4235235ft5435rerjk343f with numbers and text.

Comment: what is this `cer4235235ft5435rerjk343f` , from where you are getting ?

Comment: automatic gernerating like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFBT1VJvQZY .

Comment: @Paritosh Piplewar, cer4235235ft5435rerjk343f what are method i can generate url.

Comment: Any reason you want to show `uuid` instead of `id`?

Comment: `cer4235235ft5435rerjk343f` is just an id or thing that resides in database or may be computed dynamically. have a look on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid , it will be very helpful for you

Comment: when users can easily find /posts/6, /posts/7.. this post is hidden as possible

Comment: @Paritosh Piplewar, not show SEO friendly. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another column in the database, update it with some alpha numeric string, and use that column for querying.

eg:

Add a column `permalink` to your posts table

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_permalink

  def create_permalink
    self.permalink = SecureRandom.hex
  end
  ..
```

Change links to use this String

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(:id => post.permalink) %>
```

Modify your controller

```
def show
  @post = Post.where(:permalink => params[:id]).first
end
```

Comment: Any changes in controller? def set_post, i added but its show post id

Comment: add some text config / routes.rb

Comment: You can use the regular id (which is still the primary key) for relations. For this change, you dont need any change in routes.

Comment: i want to add `require 'securerandom'` somewhere in rails?